# Xamarin.Forms application using Google Cloud Messaging can't publish

Tags: visual-studio-2015, google-cloud-messaging, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Use Xamarin.Forms + Visual Studio 2015 and add Google Cloud Messaging Client components , when build the .Drod project then get some warning messages and publish to device and emulator will be fail .

Xamarin.Forms v2.3.2.127
Visual Studio 2015 update Xamarin for stable last version

warning messages :

Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. 
In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and         press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file: ...........

[image]

[image]

case redo steps :

(1) create new Xamarin.Forms (PCL)

(2) .Drod project Add Google Cloud Messaging Client components

(3) build project

I try modify .Droid project app.config , but still fail

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.ObjectModel" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.10.0" newVersion="4.0.10.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
```

Comment: Although, of course, you should try to get away all warnings, I've noticed that in the Android project it happens fast but also it is nothing to worry about. It should just run and work.

Comment: Project can't  publish to device and emulator , so it's not work.  just have warnings not have any errors

Comment: Ok, but these errors don't seem to cause that. When not publishing does it say anything in the output logs? Did it deploy before?

Comment: can build , but can't deploy to device or emulator , the output logs the same warnings

Comment: just for clarifying what is happening...
if you try without adding the GCM then the application is properly deployed on the device (and it runs properly).
As soon as you add the GCM, the application deployment stops working.
Is it correct?

Comment: Can you take a look in logcat (when you do the 'adb install foo.apk' command)?
 Can you post the manifest content?

Comment: yes , without add the GCM , the project build and deploy will be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are just warnings, so they should not be the root cause of the publishing failure.

Using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) in the past I ran into a similar problem and it was caused by the fact that my application package name starts with an uppercase letter.

see the following note in the xamarin GCM documentation

> It is VERY important that your application's package name does NOT start with an uppercase letter. This will cause an error in deploying your application to a simulator or device.

https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/googleplayservices-gcm

Comment: Thanks , but not this reason (package name) ,I have changed it

Comment: Hi, manifest file not sync , I change it and fixed this question , thank you